# How can I find a value from a union-type array with given parameter and infer the return type?

Tags: typescript

I have a union-type array that needs to be filtered by type.

```js
type One = {
  type: 'one';
  value: string;
}

type Two = {
  type: 'two';
  value: string;
}

type Three = {
  type: 'three';
  value: string;
}

type Union = One | Two | Three;

const array: Union[] = [...]
```

What I'm currently doing is using `as` keyword but I'm trying to make a function to handle this kind of type guard.

```js
const one = array.find(a => a.type === 'one') as One | undefined;
```

Is there any way to find a value from the array by type and have the return type inferred?

```js
function findByType(array: Union[], type: 'one' | 'two') {
  const item = array.find(a => a.type === type);
  return item
}

const one = findByType([...], 'one'); // one to be type of 'One';
```

Comment: would [this](https://tsplay.dev/WY4Rvm) fit your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's only a few types, I believe the easiest would be to create [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) for those types. (But then the type isn't fully inferred by the compiler.)

```
const isOne = (a: Union): a is One => a.type === "one"
const isTwo = (a: Union): a is Two => a.type === "two"

const one = array.find(isOne)
```

Or if you wish to use something like `findByType`.

```
function findByType<T extends Union>(array: Union[], typeCheck: (a: Union) => a is T) {
  const item = array.find(typeCheck);
  return item
}

const one = findByType(array, isOne)
```